# Eclipse IDE : Adding external commands to the menu bar or toolbar?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I have some help files that I would like to integrate on the Elcipse toolbar or menu bar. Is there any way to add commands to launch local files this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is add a custom command to your toolbar.

I think you could use this tutorial, since it describes the general approach to commands in Eclipse:

http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCommands/article.html